# How to reverse the Chrome command --allow-running-insecure-content

Tags: google-chrome, security

I have set the --allow-running-insecure-content on my Google Chrome, but now I am curious how I can set it back to only running secure content. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: How did you set the option in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

1. Type chrome://settings/ in your URL bar or go to chrome Settings by pressing the 3 dots in the top right corner.

[image: Settings]

2. Scroll down and press Show advanced settings
3. Press Content Settings located just  under **Privacy**

[image: Content settings]

4. Scroll down untill you see **Protected Content** - Enable it

[image: Protected Content]